# How do I view the mysql stored procedure execution plan?

Tags: mysql, sql, procedure

Using the JDBC Java performs a stored procedure, but slowly, so want to check the database stored procedure execution plan, what do you think?Have hundreds of lines of SQL stored procedures, database is Mysql, I know to check the select statement execution plan is to use the explain, but how can a stored procedure?

Answer (score 1):

You could use the mysql [optimizer tracer](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/internals/en/optimizer-tracing.html) if you have at least mysql v5.6.3.

Basic usage:

```
SET optimizer_trace="enabled=on";
SELECT ...; # your query here
SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.OPTIMIZER_TRACE;
# possibly more queries...
# When done with tracing, disable it:
SET optimizer_trace="enabled=off";
```

It can trace the [following queries](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/internals/en/traceable-queries.html):

> SELECT; INSERT or REPLACE (with VALUES or SELECT); UPDATE/DELETE and their multi-table variants; all the previous ones prefixed by EXPLAIN; SET (unless it manipulates the optimizer_trace system variable); DO; DECLARE/CASE/IF/RETURN (stored routines language elements); CALL. If one of those statements is prepared and executed in separate steps, preparation and execution are separately traced.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use explain on the select etc. statements separately that are within the storeed procedure.